# Multiple encoding in database

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, loading

I'm newbie working at databases, so be patient, please ;)

I've designed a table in mysql to store city names (and other stuff). I load the data from a UTF8 txt file with all the information.

The problem is that city names are written in their original form, so I've got charsets from China, Russia, England, Marocco, etc. When I load the file into the database, there are a lot of warnings because of that. I have done like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ommadawn/cities.txt' INTO TABLE myDB.cities CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (country, city, lat, lon);
```

All my charset is set to utf8 and collations too.

Where's the problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The warnings are like this:

```
Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xCC\xA7uway...' for column 'city' at row 9
```

And in this line, the text is:

```
AE  Z̧uwayhir   23.28333    53.2
```

Comment: Is the input file properly encoded with UTF-8? What do you mean by "charsets from China, Russia" etc.: different encodings (Big-5, Koi-8...) or simply different scripts (CJK, Cyrillic...)? It's hard to tell what the problem is if you don't tell more about the warnings you get.

Comment: sorry, I was out of home. Yes, the file is encoded in UTF-8. The charsets from China, etc., I meant that these languages use different characters than the english alphanumeric ones, as cyrillic, etc.

Comment: But is it *properly* encoded? Do all characters look right, or is there Mojibake? As said before, without any details about the warnings, nobody's able to help you.

Comment: I think it's properly encoded because I can open it using Kate editor, it says it's encoded in utf-8 and i can see the arabic, japanese, cyrilic, characters well. You can see the error in the new edit I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.  In UTF-8, `CCA7` is a "COMBINING CEDILLA".  So, it is destined to be combined with an adjacent letter to make an accented letter.  This page shows it as combining with the `u`; another experiment (in the *same* browser) had it combining with the `Z`: Z̧uwayhir.  Ugh.

Anyway, there seems to be such a place in the UAE.  And UTF-8 (MySQL's utf8 or utf8mb4) seems to be the encoding for it.

Back to the question...  Probably the column in the table was not declared to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Do you know if it truncated the text down to just `Z`?
Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`